# AWS CloudFront to host SSL and forward on to sendgrid not working

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, sendgrid

I am trying to have links in my emails from my application register as SSL/HTTPS secure links. This helps deliverability and other things email clients may do treating links as http vs https.

Our application is using SendGrid to send emails, which also supports click tracking on our links for us.  In order to do this SendGrid, and most other email sender services replace the original link we put in, which was an https://blahblah.com  link with their own link, http://clicktrack.sendgrid.net or something that is not https, but rather http.

SendGrid supports "white labeling" the click tracking link with something like
http://subdomain.blahblah.com  and also https version if we set it up properly.  SendGrids requirements for https/ssl link are shown here
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Add_Content/content_delivery_networks.html

Basically they are asking us to setup a CDN or other server that will host our SSL certificates, terminate the SSL, and then forward the request on to their servers.  Once that is in place they can "turn on" ssl on their end for our email links.

I tried setting this up in AWS CloudFront with the origin as sendgrid.net and the distribution having our SSL certificate and a route 53 CNAME pointing to our distribution.  So the subdomain.blahblah.com points to distribution CDN, CDN points to sendgrid, and all should work.

Testing this though it does NOT work.  If I go to the http version of subdomain it does work, CDN forwards properly.  AWS support has suggested it was an issue related to host headers and the CDN not being able to validate the origin when I had a 2nd CNAME for the origin on my subdomain2.blahblah.com.  That led me to remove 2nd cname and direclty put sendgrid as origin, but that hasn't worked and they haven't provided a solution yet.  I get error like this..

ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: pl1bS3OObC6mUd2vyyhM6bNFt3xyLsfzVIqNmiPkEO7mQgJyQCn_pA==

Any ideas welcome or a different way to do this?

Comment: Did you configure `Origin Protocol Policy` in the CloudFront distribution to "Match Viewer?"  Did you configure the default behavior to set `Forward Headers` to "None (improves caching)?"  For testing, I configured a CloudFront distro to hit "[some-string-here].ct.sendgrid.net" and it works as expected, whether I use my SSL cert in CloudFront or the built-in `https://dxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is correct, it was b/c of Forwarding all headers.  Need to not forward "Host" header.

Comment: @bjm88 im having issues integrating aws clod front and sendgrid for email links tracking, can you gave me some example of configuration on which steps to follow to do this? sadly sendgrid support dont help me on this one. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The issue was in behaviors I was forwarding all headers.  Should NOT forward "Host" header in this situation or the origin ssl call will break as it wont match expected.  AWS support did finally figure this out and recommend to me :)

Comment: I am still working to resolve a different issue after SSL is now working, getting this error from SendGrid now "Bad Hostname in Link

You have clicked on a link that contains a bad hostname. Please make sure that you have typed the link correctly."

Comment: were you able to fix this last problem? Could you share your solution?

Comment: Solved the Bad Hostname error by following the steps here https://github.com/sendgrid/docs/issues/3384
hope it helps someone